# Matchmaking Array, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I'm trying to make a javascript key-value array with the key as the name of the person and the value as a numerical one indicating their compatibility (1 lowest, 10 highest). Something like this :

```
var array = [ {name: "Sean", value: 7}, 
              {name: "Sarah", value: 8}, 
              {name: "Chloe", value: 5} ];
```

However I want to create the array somewhat dynamically, where two separate arrays- one of names and one of numbers - would make up the key-values. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Apologies- two separate "arrays". So I have an array of names and an array of values and I wanna combine that into one key-value array. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

simply by specifying the names as key and the corresponding values as value

```
var ar = {};
var name = 'xyz';
var value = 1;
ar[name] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
var array = {"Sean":7,"Sarah":8,"Chloe":5};
```

And if you want to add the items one by one:

```
var array = {};
array["Sean"] = 7;
array["Sarah"] = 8;
array["Chloe"] = 5;
```